# Pandas sort list according to a list while preserving date_time order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

I have two dataframes that looks similar. This is a head from the first one, while the second one differs in terms of spend_exc spend_pub   nr_sessions ratio. Same number users in both, as in 10 users.

```
    date_time   user spend_exc  spend_pub   nr_sessions ratio
48  2022-08-03  user1   623.3415    0.0 987     6.315517
50  2022-08-03  user2   2304.3439   0.0 2988    7.711994
51  2022-08-03  user3   5380.3535   0.0 7954    6.764337
58  2022-08-03  user4   28730.2600  0.0 44993   6.385496
64  2022-08-03  user5   46366.1278  0.0 94856   4.888054
```

I have data from 3 August until 12 August.

I want to order the dataframe so that each new_date time starts with the user with the highest spend_exc during whole dataset in descending order e.g. user5, user4 etc I want to preserve the date_time column in ascending order.

My plan was to group them and save them in a list

```
ordered_by_spend = filtered_p1.groupby(['user']).sum().sort_values(by='spend_exc', ascending=False).index.tolist()
```

However, I couldn't quite figure out how to the two dataframes based on this list so that the date_time remains in ascending order. I tried passing the list in `.sort_values(by=)` but I got errors. I'm not exactly sure how to apply this list.

**EDIT:**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
date_time_ordered_by_spend = filtered_p1.groupby(['date_time', 'user']) \
    .sum() \
    .reset_index() \
    .sort_values(by=['date_time','spend_exc'], 
                 ascending=[True, False])['date_time'] \
    .unique() \
    .tolist()

df2['date_time'] = pd.Categorical(
    df2['date_time'], categories=date_time_ordered_by_spend, ordered=True)
df2.sort_values('date_time', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi @Jeril, I'm getting a KeyError: 'date_time' when I try this one.

Comment: can you share the output of  `filtered_p1.head()`

Comment: I think you have me the right idea though. So I added 'date_time' in the groupby filtered_p1.groupby(['date_time', 'user']).sum().reset_index() which gives me the result that I want but the thing is if I apply this to the second dataframe as well. Moreover, I would like the order for each date_time to be fixed so that it doesn't fluctuate from day to day.

Comment: how does your second dataframe looks like?

Comment: Similar to the first one, same users about 10 users but the values on the other columns differ.

Comment: is it okay to concat both the dataframes? pd.concat([df1, df2])

Comment: No, I wouldn't want to concatenate them.

Comment: I have updated the solution, can you check

Comment: date_time is not an index for these two dataframes. Do they have to be in order to work? Because I'm not using it as an index.

Comment: I am considering the `date_time` as a column not index

Comment: What is `df.a` in df2['date_time'] = pd.Categorical(
    df.a, categories=date_time_ordered_by_spend, ordered=True) is that supposed to be df.user?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It is supposed to be `df2['date_time']`